# I need to make the difference between two timestamp fields, start and end

Tags: sql, hive, datediff

I need to make the difference between two timestamp fields, start and end, for example:
start_date: 2019-09-20 01:15:00
final_date: 2019-09-20 01:20:15
datediff (end_date, start_date)

the return i get is 0.

I think it's because the day is the same, but I would like to have the differences in minutes, where in this case would be 5 minutes.

Has anyone had this difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to convert to Unix timestamps:

```
select (unix_timestamp(final_date) - unix_timestamp(start_date)) / 60 as diff_minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)() returns the number of days between two dates or datetimes. 
To have the seconds between two timestamp you can take the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)(date) to return the unix time so do

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-20 01:20:00')-UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-20 01:15:00'))/60;
```

or using [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2019-09-20 01:15:00','2019-09-20 01:20:00')
```